# what do I use to perform SQL-like lookups on a java table?

Tags: java, sql

I have a 2D array

```
public static class Status{
public static String[][] Data= {
{ "FriendlyName","Value","Units","Serial","Min","Max","Mode","TestID","notes" },
{ "PIDs supported [01 – 20]:",null,"Binary","0",null,null,"1","0",null },
{ "Online Monitors since DTCs cleared:",null,"Binary","1",null,null,"1","1",null },
{ "Freeze DTC:",null,"NONE IN MODE 1","2",null,null,"1","2",null },
```

I want to

```
SELECT "FriendlyName","Value" FROM Data WHERE "Mode" = "1" and "TestID" = "2"
```

How do I do it?   The fastest execution time is important because there could be hundreds of these per minute.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't actually use a database? HSQLDB and Derby are both pretty fast and light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a lookup table. 90% of the data is referenced from near the top.

```
    public static int lookupReferenceInTable (String instanceMode, String instanceTID){
        int ModeMatches[]=getReferencesToMode(Integer.parseInt(instanceMode));
        int lineLookup = getReferenceFromPossibleMatches(ModeMatches, instanceTID);
        return lineLookup;
    }



        private static int getReferenceFromPossibleMatches(int[] ModeMatches, String instanceTID) {
      int counter = 0;
      int match = 0;
      instanceTID=instanceTID.trim();
      while ( counter < ModeMatches.length ){
         int x = ModeMatches[counter];
         if (Data[x][DataTestID].equals(instanceTID)){
         return ModeMatches[counter];
         }
         counter ++ ;
      }
      return match;

    }
```

It can be further optimized so that instead of looping through all of the arrays it will loop on column until it finds a match, then loop the next, then the next.  The data is laid out in a flowing and well organized manner so a lookup based on 3 criteria should only take a number of checks equal to the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Think about how general it needs to be.  The solution for something truly as general as SQL probably doesn't look much like the solution for a few very specific queries.

As you present it, I'd be inclined to avoid the 2D array of strings and instead create a collection - probably an ArrayList, but if you're doing frequent insertions & deletions maybe a LinkedList would be more appropriate - of some struct-like class.  So

```
 List<MyThing> list = new ArrayList<MyThing>();
```

and index the fields on which you want to search using a HashMap:

```
 Map<Integer, MyThing> modeIndex = new HashMap<Integer, MyThing>()
 for (MyThing thing : list)
     modeIndex.put(thing.mode, thing);
```

Writing it down makes me realize that won't do, in and of itself, because multiple things could have the same mode.  So probably a multimap instead - or roll your own by making the value type of the map not MyThing, but rather List.  [Google Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) has a fine multimap implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but it is possible to run some Java RDBMs with their tables entirely in your JVM's memory.  For example, [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch01.html#N101CA).  This will give you the full power of SQL selects without the overheads of disc access.  The only catch is that you won't be able to query a raw Java data structure like you are asking.  You'll first have to insert the data into the DB's in-memory tables.

(I've not tried this ... perhaps someone could comment if this approach is really viable.)

Answer (score 0):

As to your actual *question*, in C# they used to use [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) (Language Integrated Query) for this, which takes benefit of the language's support for [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29). Right now with Java 6 as the latest official release, Java doesn't support closures, but it's going to [come](http://javac.info/) in the shortly upcoming Java 7. The Java 7 based equivalent for LINQ is likely going to be [JaQue](http://code.google.com/p/jaque/).

As to your actual *problem*, you're definitely using a wrong datastructure for the job. Your best bet will be to convert the `String[][]` into a `List<Entity>` and using convenient searching/filtering API's provided by [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), as suggested by Carl Manaster. The [`Iterables#filter()`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) would be a good start.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I took a look at your array, and I think this is definitely a job for RDBMS. If you want in-memory datastructure like features (fast/no need for DB server), embedded in-memory databases like HSQLDB, H2 can provide those.

If you want good execution time, you MUST have a good datastructure. If you just have data stored in a 2D array unordered, you'll be mostly stuck with O(n).

What you need is indexes for example, just like other RDBMS. For example, if you use a lot of `WHERE` clause like this `WHERE name='Brian' AND last_name='Smith'` you could do something like this (kind of a pseudocode):

```
Set<Entry> everyEntry = //the set that contains all data
Map<String, Set<Entry>> indexedSet = newMap();
for(String name : unionSetOfNames){
    Set<Entry> subset = Iterables.collect(new HasName(name), everyEntries);
    indexedSet.put(name, subset);
}
//and later...
Set<Entry> brians = indexedSet.get("Brian");
Entry target = Iterables.find(new HasLastName("Smith"),brians);
```

(Please forgive me if the Guava API usage is wrong in the example code (it's pseudo-code!, but you get the idea).

In the above code, you'll be doing a lookup of O(1) once, and then another O(n) lookup, but on a much much smaller subset. So this can be more effective than doing a O(n) lookup on the entire set, etc. If you use a ordered Set, ordered by the `last_name` and use binary search, that lookup will become O(log n). Things like that. There are bunch of datastructures out there and this is only a very simple example.

So in conclusion, if I were you, I'll define my own classes and create a datastructure using some standard datastructures available in JDK. If that doesn't suffice, I might look at some other datastructures out there, but if it gets really complex, I think I'd just use some in-memory RDBMS like HSQLDB or H2. They are easy to embed, so there are quite close to having your own in-memory datastructure. And as more and more you do complex stuff, chances are that that option provides better performance.

Note also that I used the [Google Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library in my sample code.. They are excellent, and I highly recommend to use them because it's so much nicer. Of course don't forget to look at the java.utli.collections package, too..